# How to make normalised mutual information be range from 0 to 1

Tags: mutual-information

- Hx Marginal entropy for a discrete random variable (x)
- Hy Marginal entropy for a discrete random variable (y)
- Hxy Joint entropy for a discrete random variables (x and y)

MI = Hx+Hy-Hxy

Methods of Normalization MI:

- marginal MI = 2*( Hx + Hy - Hxy ) / ( Hx + Hy )
- joint MI = 2*( Hx + Hy - Hxy ) / ( Hxy )
- min.marginal MI = ( Hx + Hy - Hxy ) / min(Hx,Hy)
- max.marginal MI = ( Hx + Hy - Hxy ) /max(Hx,Hy)
- min.conditional MI = ( Hx + Hy - Hxy ) / min(Hx.y,Hy.x)
- max.conditional MI = ( Hx + Hy - Hxy ) / max(Hx.y,Hy.x)

ref: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HDMD/HDMD.pdf

All above normalization methods can not guarantee the range [0,1] of NMI.

What should I do to make NMI be [0,1]? My last aim is to calculate the distance as 1- NMI. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In R I would use something like this with the raw MI measures:

```
range0to1 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
```

Comment: Is this kind of normalised method suitable to MI? The simplist method is to divide max(x).

Comment: I have to say I am not an expert in information theory but I don't really see a problem here. I guess you want to render the MIs better comparable right?

Comment: I'd want to make a distance via NMI.